# Stream file content as program input

Tags: python, input, automated-tests

I'm solving some coding challenges.

- The program (1) is a script.
- When it is run, it requires the user to input some test cases (3) then splits out the output (4).

How can I create (use) a program (2) that runs the program (1), takes a text file (`input.txt`) content as input (3), feeds the input to program (1), gets output (4), and compares (4) to the `output.txt` file content (desired output).

### Addition information

#### Here is what I have been doing.

- I need to run the program by using `python <script>`
- Enter the input.
- Look at the output.
- Compare it the desired output. (subjected to human error)

#### Sample program

- `main.py`

```py
def add(a, b):
  # return a + b
  return a + b + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = int(input())
  b = int(input())
  retval = add(a, b)
  print(retval)
```

- `input.txt`

```
1
2
```

- `output.txt`

```
3
```

**Goal**

- Run another program (1)
- Feed program (1) input
- Take program (1) input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shadow the `input` function, and then run the program. The new `input` function won't ask the human user for input. Instead, `input` will read the input from a file.

```
import pathlib as pl

def get_integers_from_file(path):
    path = pl.Path(str(path))
    lyst = list()
    with open(str(path), mode="r") as inf:
        for line in inf:
            lyst.append(int(line.strip()))
    return lyst

inputs = get_integers_from_file("input.txt")
output = get_integers_from_file("output.txt.py")

class InputHijacker:
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self._inputs = inputs
        self._state = 0
    def __call__(i):
        r = i._inputs[i._state]
        i._state += 1
        return r

class PrintHijacker:
    print = print
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        file_path = str(pl.Path(str(file_path)))
        self._file = open(file_path, mode="w")

    def __call__(self, *args, sep=" ", end="\n", file=""):
        # discard/ignore input argument `file`
        return type(self).print(*args, sep=sep, end=end, file=self._file)

    def __del__(self):
        self._file.close()

input = InputHijacker(inputs)
# `input` no longer prompts the user
print = PrintHijacker("program_output.txt")
# `print` no longer prints output to sys.stdout

def add(a, b):
  # return a + b
  return a + b + 1

##################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = int(input())
  b = int(input())
  retval = add(a, b)
  print(retval)

  correct_out = get_integers_from_file("output.txt.py")
  program_out = get_integers_from_file("program_output.txt")
  for idx in range(len(program_out)):
      assert(correct_out[idx] == program_out[idx])
```